# Showing OpenStreetMap tile boundary using OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers-2, openstreetmap, tiles, style

I have a local tile source of OSM tiles.  I'd like to show the tile zoom, x, y on the tile so that I can optimize and create small offline groups of tile for specific areas (polygons).

I can get the tile boundary to show by setting a negative gutter, but I need the tile url info (zoom, x, y) to help with the manual optimization.

I saw an online resource a while back that showed this exact information on a map, but I've lost it.

Here is my layer

```
var newLayer = new OpenLayers.Layer.OSM("GC-h", "tiles/GC/composite_h/${z}/${x}/${y}.png", {numZoomLevels: 19, gutter: -1, isBaseLayer: false});
map.addLayer(newLayer);
```

Answer (score 2):

After half an hour of searching I found a service which generates images with your custom size and text. You can use this, and put x/y/z as text: `http://placehold.it/256x256&text=12/123/321`

[image: Sample image with given URL]

It may have limiting usage terms.